# Python get weighted mean of dict keys based on dict values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, mean, weighted-average

I am trying to write code to find the mean of the keys in my dict, but based on the dict values. So, for example, for:

```
d = {1:2, 2:1, 3:2}
```

the dict keys would be:

```
[1,1,2,3,3]
```

I've written the following code, which works for small data sets such as the above:

```
def get_median_of_dict_keys(d: dict) -> float:
    nums_list = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if type(v) != int:
            raise TypeError
        nums_list.extend([k] * v)
    
    median = sum(nums_list) / len(nums_list)
    return median
```

This gets me the values I want when the data set is small, but if the data set is something like:

```
d = {1:1_000_000_000_000_000, 2:2_000, 3:1_000_000_000_000_000}
```

I get an out of memory error which, now that I think about it, makes sense.

So how can I structure the above function in a way that will also handle those larger data sets? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think your code computes the mean

Comment: the keys of `d = {1:2, 2:1, 3:2}` are `1,2,3` not `1,1,2,3,3`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `{1:2, 2:1, 3:2}` should be `[1,1,2,3,3]`?

Comment: Dani, sorry, thats what I meant.

Comment: Ironkey, I know, but I need to count each key individually, or as its own entry.

Comment: alright so you want `n` keys where the value of that key is `n`?

Comment: Ann, so I need to count each key individually. So the "1" key has a value of two, so I need to count it twice. If the key was 5 and the value was 14, I'd need to treat it as though there were fourteen 5's. Almost like a voting tally that might've been done in grade school, i.e. 14 people voted for 5.

Comment: Ironkey, exactly. Again, the code works with small numbers, but once they get large, I run out of memory.

Comment: Edit your question to find the mean, or you actually want the median?

Comment: ^ what do you want, mean or median?

Comment: Thanks, folks, I did edit the title. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Removed tag `median` since you want to find `mean` specifically `weighted-mean` so added both of them

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a list, just keep two running variables, one holding the total sum and the other one holding the number of elements:

```
def get_mean_of_dict_keys(d: dict) -> float:
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for k, v in d.items():
        total += k * v
        count += v

    mean = total / count
    return mean


print(get_mean_of_dict_keys({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2}))
```

**Output**

```
2.0
```

Comment: Dani, thank you so much! I actually started thinking about this a bit after I asked the question. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the mean

this is perfectly attainable with larger numbers:

```
import numpy as np
d = {1:2000000000, 2:1000, 3:2000000000}
print(np.mean([i*d[i] for i in d]))
```

**output**

```
2666667333.3333335
```

**breakdown**

```
[i*d[i] for i in d]

# is equivalent to:

lst = []
for i in d:
    lst.append(i*d[i])
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to find is [**`weighted average`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).

#### Formula:

[image]

Where,

- `X1..n` are keys in your dictionary.
- `W1..n` are values in your dictionary.
- `X̅` is weighted average.

#### Pure Python approach.

Using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) with [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul)

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul
d = {1:2, 2:1, 3:2}
sum(starmap(mul, d.items()))/sum(d.values())
# 2.0
```

#### If you want to use `NumPy`

You can use [`np.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) here.

```
np.average([*d.keys()], weights=[*d.values()])
# 2.0
```